# Auto Scroll CSS3

Tags: css, xhtml

I been looking on the internet for a css3 feature that will allow me to scroll a certain div.

Now why do I only wanna use this, well because I'm creating a profile whitch only allows me to use CSS...

So if anybody has some info on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 and transitions, perhaps something like this:

```
#mydiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 1.0s ease;
}
#mydiv:hover {
  top: -100px;
  transition: top 1.0s ease;
}
```

This should make it scroll up on hover.  To make it 'scroll', you can make sure that this is inside a container with overflow: hidden.

This is untested, but if it looks like this is what you want, there are loads of resources online for CSS3 animations.